# Code / Process for running rmarkdown in base R

Tags: r

All my codes developed in base R and I don't want to use RStudio, however I want to use rmarkdown feature in base R which is available in Rstudio.

I have downloaded rmarkdown package in base r, but not able to derive a code to publish my work

All the output of my codes written in R should be view able through web browser.

Comment: R Markdown is using pandoc to generate html/pdfs. Try looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're using `.Rmd` as your file extension. If not, rename it to a `.Rmd` extension. Make sure [you have Pandoc installed](https://pandoc.org/installing) on your OS.

Next, add the following to the top of the file:

```
---
title: "Your notebook title"
output: html_document
---
```

`output`: could take any value. You can pass in the value of `ioslides_presentation` for example if you want but it looks like `html_document` fits the criteria of what you want pretty well.

Once you have that, write your code in any editor (or the R console if you prefer). Use the code chunks and markdown text formatting as you normally would:

````
```{r}
plot(1:10)
```
````

In my base R Console, this is how `mynotebook.Rmd` looks like:
[image]

Finally, use the `render()` function from `rmarkdown`. You can either attach it and run `render()`:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("mynotebook.Rmd")
```

Or, run `rmarkdown::render("mynotebook.Rmd")`.

Notice that the use of RStudio is not required at all since Pandoc is the document converter performing this task. For the so inclined, this is what its documentation has to say:

> When you run render, R Markdown feeds the `.Rmd` file to `knitr`,
>   which executes all of the code chunks and creates a new markdown (.md)
>   document which includes the code and it's output.
>
> The markdown file generated by `knitr` is then processed by **pandoc**
>   which is responsible for creating the finished format.
>
> This may sound complicated, but R Markdown makes it extremely simple
>   by encapsulating all of the above processing into a single render
>   function.